# Addidng runnable in Autosar Davinci configurator

Tags: operating-system, runnable, autosar

The task mapping window of Davinci Configurator Pro displays a set of already added runnable. I am not able to add new runnable. I am new to AUTOSAR and Davinci tool

Comment: This is a very specific question that should better be directed at the support team of the software vendor.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to create a SWCD (SoftwareComponentDescription) for an SWC with another tool, since DaVinci Configurator (Pro) can only configure and parameterize the BSW and RTE, but you can not directly create SWCDs with it. It might be possible with the License Option MD or Developer.

You should be able to import an existing SWCD in DaVinci Configurator and then map the runnable defined in the SWCDs to the tasks though.

Answer (score 0):

New runnables are created in the DaVinci Developer and not in configurator. Right click on the dpa file and use the davinci assistant to open the swc through da vinci developer. Open the swc component and create a new runnable. Now, save the developer and the configurator should pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

Once you create the Runnable in the developer please give the trigger point to the Runnable either periodic or event(Received data or operation invocation) based.
Once you added above changes sync developer with configurator then you can see your Runnable under mapping...
Hope this will help..

Answer (score -1):

I am using DaVinci Developer . In the window with task i can find in the specified list (5 ms , 10 ms, init, events,etc) my task.
the with right click i can assign to task and from task i can order them.